# Error al usar "npm start" en un proyecto de React

Tags: reactjs, npm

Básicamente acabo de crear un nuevo proyecto de React, quise iniciarlo, con el comando "npm start" pero no me deja ejecutarlo, me sale este error:

```
**Starting the development server...
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myfirstapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myfirstapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T22_15_56_751Z-debug.log**
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses YARN, va mas rápido y genera menos errores.

Answer (score 2):

Paso 1: `npm cache clean --force`

Paso 2: Elimine `node_modules` mediante la carpeta `rm -rf node_modules` o elimínelo manualmente yendo al directorio y haga clic con el botón derecho, eliminar. Eliminar el archivo `package-lock.json` también.

Paso 3: `npm install`

Inicielo de nuevo `npm start`

Esto funcionó para mí. Espera que funcione para ti también.

**Nota:** Aún así, si estás allí, verifica el error que muestra en rojo y actúe en consecuencia. Este error es específico del entorno node.js. Feliz codificación!!

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!
Cuando mi npm start no quiere arrancar, busco en la terminal de Linux el proceso y lo mato usando `kill -9 [número de proceso]` y de nuevo `npm start`

Saludos.